# How to associate User Logged to Models in a Form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a problem. In my project, I need to associate the User logged in a forms to my Models. A forms contains ('user_logged', 'name', 'description' and 'conclusion'), and I wish the forms get user logged automatically, and other fields I will put manually. I try this in my models:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But I fill in my forms, and dont get my user logged, the results for user is: "None".

My views below:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CreateTarefa(CreateView):
model = Tarefa
fields = ['nome_tarefa', 'descricao', 'concluida']
template_name = 'tarefa_form.html'
```

Thanks a lot.
Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

In your form when you simply receive the `get` method, then add `initial` values to the form like the following:

```
form = MyForm()
form.initial = {'user_logged':request.user}
```

or

```
form = MyForm({'user_logged':request.user})
```

For CBV, you just need to access the `get_form_kwargs()` method and add the `logged in` user:

```
class CreateTarefa(CreateView):
    model = Tarefa
    fields = ['nome_tarefa', 'descricao', 'concluida']
    template_name = 'tarefa_form.html'


    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
         return dict(super(CreateTarefa, self).get_form_kwargs(*args,
                **kwargs),**{'user_logged': self.request.user})
```

Comment: hmm, i had been tried this. And dont work, the Django needs for __init__ for variable 'user_loged', and a dont understand where i will create __init__ and how do create this. Can you help me how do create this __init__ and where? thanks my friend

The error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_logged'

Comment: if you have tried, what is the error that you got? show me

Comment: this error: 
The web page: TypeError at /create_tarefa/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_logged'

The console:   File "C:\Users\Matheus Soares\ProjetoIlhaSoft\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_logged'

Comment: with FBV it's pretty much simpler, can you edit your question with your current code, your current function

Comment: Can I do this? Can you explain this for me in detail?

Comment: With function based view, you can do it with less code (I think), and you will able to send the logged in use a way that you will understand quickly

Comment: I can do work with form, with CBV i cant do this :/.
I used 'tarefa.user_logged = request.user' in my view create and works fine.